# Google Cloud Datastore how to create, update and delete entity with http request

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

As Google Cloud Datastore [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/client-libraries) are available for some language only. Now, How can do operation like create, update and delete of entity without using client libraries with HTTP request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Datastore API is built on HTTP and JSON, so any standard HTTP client can send requests to it and parse the responses.You can find more about building a [flexible run time here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build)

Answer (score 1):

One of the classic way to do this is to expose the datastore CRUD operations through a set of REST APIs. Google offers Cloud Endpoints which are a set of "tools, libraries and capabilities that allow you to generate APIs and client libraries from an App Engine application" https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/
You can have a look at this tutorial https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-1-b571ad6c7cd2#.1j9holpdt